# He realizado una aplicación con tabs y tengo un datepicker para seleccionar la fecha.¿Cómo puedo hacer para que se actualice la fecha en el textview?

Tags: android

La clase principal contiene 3 fragments:

```
public class Mostrar_Detalles_Alojamientos extends AppCompatActivity implements DatePickerFragment.OnDateSelectedListener,DatePickerFragment2.OnDateSelectedListener2
{

/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
 * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
 * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
 * may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
public static String idCasa;

public   String extra;
//private String extra;


/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
private ViewPager mViewPager;
public static void launch(Activity activity, String idCasa) {
    Intent intent = getLaunchIntent(activity, idCasa);
    activity.startActivityForResult(intent, Constantes.CODIGO_DETALLE);
}

/**
 * Construye un Intent a partir del contexto y la actividad
 * de detalle.
 *
 * @param context Contexto donde se inicia
 * @param idCasa  Identificador de la meta
 * @return Intent listo para usar
 */
public static Intent getLaunchIntent(Context context, String idCasa) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, Mostrar_Detalles_Alojamientos.class);
    intent.putExtra(Constantes.EXTRA_ID, idCasa);
    return intent;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_actividad1);
    // Retener instancia
    if (getIntent().getStringExtra(Constantes.EXTRA_ID) != null)
        idCasa = getIntent().getStringExtra(Constantes.EXTRA_ID);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });


}




@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_actividad1, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}



/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */


    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";



}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        switch(position){
            case 0:
                fragment_1 fragmento1 = new fragment_1();
                return fragmento1;
            case 1:
                fragment_2 fragmento2 = new fragment_2();
                return fragmento2;
            case 2:
                fragment_3 fragmento3 = new fragment_3();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.container, new fragment_3(), "fragment_3")
                        .commit();
                return fragmento3;

        }


        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "Detalles";
            case 1:
                return "Contactar";
            case 2:
                return "Reservas";
        }
        return null;
    }




}
public void onDateSelected(int year, int month, int day) {


    fragment_3 Fragment = (fragment_3)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("fragment_3");


    if (Fragment != null) {

        Fragment.actualizarFecha(year, month, day);
    }


}

public void onDateSelected2(int year, int month, int day) {

    fragment_3 insertFragment = (fragment_3)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("fragment_3");


    if (insertFragment != null) {
        insertFragment.actualizarFecha2(year, month, day);
    }

}

}
```

En la pestaña 3 necesito que cuando seleccione una fecha en el datepicker el Textview se actualice.

No se produce ningún error me aparece el calendario, me deja seleccionar la fecha sin problemas pero no se me actualiza la fecha en el Textview correspondiente.

Tengo hecha la misma aplicación sin pestañas y me funciona correctamente a ver si alguien me da una explicación.

Este es el código de la pestaña 3:(fragment_3):

```
public class fragment_3 extends Fragment {
// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;


private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public fragment_3() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Habilitar al fragmento para contribuir en la action bar
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}


// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}


public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}

private static final String TAG = fragment_3.class.getSimpleName();


private TextView User,id_Casa;
public TextView fecha_fin;
public TextView fecha_ini;
public String usu;
private Button reservas;
int entrada=0;
int salida=-1;
int id;
int value=-1;
private Gson gson = new Gson();
View v;






@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflando layout del fragmento
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_3, container, false);

    // Obtención de instancias controles

    usu=cad_username;
    User = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_Id_Precio);
    id_Casa = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_Id_Casa);
    fecha_ini = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtFechaIn);
    fecha_fin=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtFechaOut);
    //User.setText(user);
    obtenerId_user();
    id_Casa.setText(idCasa+" / "+titulo1);
    fecha_ini.setText(""+2019+"-"+10+"-"+10);
    fecha_ini.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    DialogFragment picker = new DatePickerFragment();
                    picker.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");

                }
            }
    );
    fecha_fin.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    DialogFragment picker1 = new DatePickerFragment2();
                    picker1.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");

                }
            }
    );


    reservas=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btnInsertarPrecio);

    reservas.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!camposVacios()) {
                guardarReserva();
            }else  {
                Toast.makeText(
                        getActivity(),
                        "Completa los campos",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }
    });

    return v;
}



public void actualizarFecha(int ano, int mes, int dia) {
    // Setear en el textview la fecha


    entrada=Integer.valueOf(ano+(mes+1)+dia);
    Toast.makeText(
            getActivity(),
            ""+ano+"-"+(mes+1)+"-"+dia,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();// El toast me lo muestra con la fecha seleccionada en el datepicker, pero no se me actualiza el TextView

    fecha_ini.setText(new StringBuilder().append(ano)
            .append("-").append(mes+1).append("-").append(dia)
            .append(" "));

}

public void actualizarFecha2(int ano, int mes, int dia) {
    // Setear en el textview la fecha

    fecha_fin.setText(ano + "-" + (mes + 1) + "-" + dia);
    salida=Integer.valueOf(ano+(mes+1)+dia);

}

}// Final de la clase
```

Comment: Has probado solo colocando `fecha_ini.setText(ano + "-" + (mes+1) + "-" + dia);`. Y el TextView `fecha_fin` te muestra la fecha?

Comment: Ese no es el problema de las dos maneras debería funcionar

Answer (score 0):

Estas inicializando el `fragment_3` 2 veces por lo que estas utilizando la instancia equivocada. Cuando inicializas el `fragment_3` en el `case`, tambien lo inicializas cuando inicializas la transaccion.

Lo inicializas tanto al inicio:

```
fragment_3 fragmento3 = new fragment_3();
```

Y tambien en la transaccion:

```
 .add(R.id.container, new fragment_3(), "fragment_3")
```

Enviale la primera instancia y asi estaras utilizando el fragment que esta siendo visualizado:

```
 fragment_3 fragmento3 = new fragment_3();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.container, fragmento3 , "fragment_3")
                        .commit();
                return fragmento3;
```

Comment: Tiene lógica lo que me dices pero si hago eso me da error, me dice que ya está definido fragment_3.

Comment: Lo he resuelto convirtiendo las variables del fragment_3 a static y setteandolas desde la actividad principal.

Comment: public void onDateSelected2(int year, int month, int day) {

        fragment_3 insertFragment = (fragment_3)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("fragment_3");

        if (insertFragment != null) {
            //insertFragment.actualizarFecha2(year, month, day);
            fecha_fin.setText(year + "-" + (month + 1) + "-" + day);
        }
    }